# Adding GTM to a website with GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a website that has been using GA for some time. Now someone wants me to add it to theirs GTM and replace my snippet with that GTM tag.

I don't know how to use GTM and don't really want to dig into that :/

My website was working just fine... Is there some easy way to make GTM just a simple middle man that looks at my domain and just throw everything directly to GA?

I manage to make it so GA gets info on the website traffic like active users etc. however that website has scripts that fires events to GA.

After googling a while i think this is because GTM adds some random names to the trackers and my code calls `ga('send', ... )` directly :/

I know i can make a custom tag in GTM but they want it to be UA tag -_-.

Is there any way to set a default name for my trigger in GTM settings? Or some other solution?

atm. i have a code with gtm tag only and I'd rather avoid changing my web code if possible.

---

### Edit

Ok, could someone explain to me how to achieve this:

I have this code:

```
var a = $('meta[property="a"]').attr('content');
var b = $('meta[property="b"]').attr('content');

ga('send','event',a,event,b);
```

where `event` is one of several possible strings of for example 
 `'event_1'`,`'event_2'` or`'event_3'`

and my GA has 3 goals that have `action` = `'event_1'` etc.

How do i replace this with GTM and dataLayer?

Comment: Could you add examples of the "random names in the trackers".

Comment: apparently whenever GTM injects a tag it create a new tracker with a given name like you would use `ga("create", "UA-123456-1","{name: "gtm145445454545"}"` and if my code calls `ga('send', ...)` it won't work, it would need to be `ga('gtm145445454545.send',...)`. I've already found out i'm suppose to use something called `dataLayer` for thing like this but i'm not particularly happy to rewrite a code that works fine -_-.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you can give the GA pixel a label through the GTM, so it doesn't use a random one. But I'm really not sure. I use GTM a lot but I always include GA seperately into the website.

Comment: you mean you have both GA snippet and GTM tag in your code? I was told im gonna go to hell for that [;

Comment: Yes, that's what I have and I find it a better solution. When the GTM doesn't work by accident or you have a bug in there or some kind of AdBlock thing, GA will  not be affected and still work. Google's network is also so well optimized that there is barely latency, and you still load both of the scripts asyncronously. Also, the marketing people and analysts who mainly use the GTM will not have a chance to kill GA by accident.

Comment: Another possible solution would be to include GA as a custom script, and not use the GA tag template from GTM ;-)

Comment: I do not understand your use case. This is your website, so you could simply throw GTM out altogether. Alternatively you run your GA unmodified and not add GA tags (with the same tracking id) in GTM - it's fine to run both side by side, it's just mixed implementations that are a nuisance. Else go the advanced settings of the GA tag, check "set tracker name" and leave the field empty (this will create a tracker with the default name).

Comment: ok, it's not "my" website. It's a website i make for someone and he has many other. I am fully aware that this problem is stupid... i want to downvote my own question every time i read it... . The ridiculous specification i got is that there must be one GTM tag (shared with other sites), no GA snippets and the Tag in GTM must be a UA tag not custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread has 2 questions :

1.- Migrate a hardcode implementation of Google Universal into Tag Manager is not so simple as copy and replace the Universal Main Snipper for the GTM Code.
Look for this google guide to migrate.  Has more or less the steps needed and the one to take in consideration during the migration.

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#migration

If you goes for GTM, it's higly recomended to remove your ga() function on the page, this will stop working and you javascript too. Basically this mean, remove all your Google Analytics of the domains and install GTM and configure the corrects tags. Try to avoid things like paste the Google Analytics code inside a custom HTML tag, it's a very bad practice, but is see that a lot. Plan your migration

2.- Regarding the event you have to do :

Create a tag of universal analytics events and activate when you pushes a GTM event, them manage this values via the dataLayer
Let this link for more information:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164470?hl=en

```js
var a = $('meta[property="a"]').attr('content');
var b = $('meta[property="b"]').attr('content');
dataLayer.push({'event': 'ga_event' , 'cat' : a , 'act' : b})
```

Try to involve more yourself in the GTM and Universal's World before ask, i'm not trying to be an asshole, but this question involves so many things that can be solved just looking the documentation, and somany thing to examplain in a single post.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that is exactly what i needed! I know i'm being a noob here and i'm sorry for that but it's like one time thing for me and i didn't really wanted to dive into this too much. Again thank you for your time :)

Comment: you're welcome ! :), don't hesitate to create a specific question with a specific issue (when you find one). Also i remembered this tutorial, it can help a lot if you want to start from the very beginning.
https://analyticsacademy.withgoogle.com/course/5/unit/1/lesson/1